# Convert service data to google charts data format - Angularjs - JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, google-visualization

I have a service result of data below. It will expand surely. And I use google charts to show this data. But I did it static at the moment. Is there an easy way to convert my bunch of data that comes from the service to a json format easily. I do not want to use a foreach loop to generate that string for the google chart data. I also use angularjs in my project. Thanks to any help

```
[
  {
    "date": "2013-05-01",
    "amount": null,
    "imprCount": 120,
    "clickCount": 141
  },
  {
    "date": "2013-05-02",
    "amount": null,
    "imprCount": 1122,
    "clickCount": 125
  },
  {
    "date": "2013-05-03",
    "amount": null,
    "imprCount": 1782,
    "clickCount": 1154
  }
]

//Chart Data
chartIncome.data = {"cols": [
        {/*id: "month",*/ label: "Month", type: "string"},
        {/*id: "income-id",*/ label: "Income", type: "number"}
    ], "rows": [
        {c: [
            {v: "2013-05-01"},
            {v: 12}
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "2013-05-02"},
            {v: 25}
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "2013-05-03"},
            {v: 203}

        ]},
        {c: [
             {v: "2013-05-04"},
             {v: 1002}

         ]}
    ]};
```

Comment: You you just asking how to convert the array of data into the chartIncome.data format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are going to have process your data one way or another and it seems the easiest way is to just create a function to convert the json data array into the format that google charts is looking for.  I know you said you don't want to use a foreach loop, but in order to convert the data you are going to have to process it.   A function like this can work.

```
function processArray(json) {
  var chartData = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = json.length; i < l; i++) {
    chartData.push({ c: [ { v: json[i].date, {v:json[i].clickCount}]});
  }
  return chartData;
}
```

Assuming you are making an angular service call from a controller something like this:

```
Service.getData().then(function(data) {
  var chartData = processArray(data);
   chartIncome.data = {"cols": [
      { label: "Month", type: "string"},
      { label: "Income", type: "number"}
      ], "rows": chartData
    };
});
```